# How to build a data loader from list in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, resnet, pytorch-dataloader

I got one list of images and another list of labels.
Image: shape(64, 64, 3)
Label: shape(64,). actually, labels are 64-dimensional continuous values.

```
import pickle

file_name = "trainData.pkl"
open_file = open(file_name, "rb")
loaded_list = pickle.load(open_file)
open_file.close()

print(loaded_list[0])
print(loaded_list[0].shape)

file_name = "trainLabel.pkl"
open_file = open(file_name, "rb")
loaded_list = pickle.load(open_file)
open_file.close()

print(loaded_list[0])
print(loaded_list[0].shape)
```

Comment: hey, it would be better if you tried to create it yourself first and then use stack overflow to ask if you encounter any problems. But anyways, this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65143771/8909353